# tvOS: applicationWillResignActive/applicationDidBecomeActive not called when displaying a system popup

Tags: tvos

In my tvOS game, when I trigger a system popup (i.e. Hold "HOME" to bring up the "SLEEP/CANCEL" popup, or an In-App Purchase confirmation prompt), the applicationWillResignActive/applicationDidBecomeActive functions are not called.

However they are called **correctly** when I suspend/resume the app (i.e. Hold the "MENU" button, multitasking), but not when these popups are showing.

This is an issue for me, because I need my game to pause when these popups are showing.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there any way to determine when these popups are showing on tvOS?

- I looked at some sample apps (DemoBots) and it has the same behavior.
- When running the code as an iOS app, it works correctly
- Games on the Apple TV App store work correctly.

Code is straight forward

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground");
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background,     optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its a bug with tvOS 9.0. 
Updating to the latest version of XCode and device firmware - and the problem goes away